# Flutter package_info

Tags: flutter

I want to use package_info to show the version number and build of my app in the about screen. On android phones it works well but on ios I have an error:

> Receiver: null
>   Tried calling: toUpperCase()

Part of my Code looks like

```
class _AboutState extends State<About> {
  Future<PackageInfo> _getPackageInfo() async {
    PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
    return packageInfo;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var now = new DateTime.now();
    String yearNow = DateFormat('yyyy').format(now);

    return FutureBuilder<PackageInfo>(
        future: _getPackageInfo(), // a previously-obtained Future<String> or null
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<PackageInfo> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return new Material(
                color: HexToColor('#508bbb'),
                child: new Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Text(snapshot.data.appName.toUpperCase(), style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0)),
```

Any help is appreciated. If there is a better proposal do not hesitate ;)

Comment: I guess `snapshot.data.appName` is not `String`. Maybe `snapshot.data.appName.toString().toUpperCase()` ?

Comment: you're right ! thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because `snapshot.data.appName` is not `String`.Change it to `snapshot.data.appName.toString().toUpperCase()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

On IOS

> snapshot.data.appName.toString().toUpperCase()

still returns NULL. I found following solution [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/42510#issuecomment-594275815) saying that you have to add it in the Info.plist file